# f:convertDateTime with LocalDateTime throws "Cannot format given Object as a Date"

Tags: jsf, localdatetime

I have a local date time property:

```java
private LocalDatetime date;
```

I want to show it in this format `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`:

```xml
<h:outputText value="#{transaction.date}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
</h:outputText>
```

But I got this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<f:convertDateTime>` defaults currently still to `java.util.Date` as expected date type and is currently not (yet?) capable of automatically detecting the date type. It will under the covers incorrectly continue to use [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) instead of [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to format the `LocalDateTime`. This specific exception is coming from `SimpleDateFormat`.

You need to explicitly set the `type` attribute of the `<f:convertDateTime>` tag to the desired date type if your actual date value is not a `java.util.Date`. You can find a list of supported types in in [tag documentation](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/vdldoc/f/convertdatetime):

| Name | Required | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **`type`** | `false` | `javax.el.ValueExpression` <sub>(*must evaluate* to `java.lang.String`)</sub> | Specifies what contents the string value will be formatted to include, or parsed expecting. Valid values are "**date**", "**time**", "**both**", "**localDate**", "**localDateTime**", "**localTime**", "**offsetTime**", "**offsetDateTime**", and "**zonedDateTime**". The values starting with "local", "offset" and "zoned" correspond to Java SE 8 Date Time API classes in package `java.time` with the name derived by upper casing the first letter. For example, `java.time.LocalDate` for the value "localDate". Default value is "date". |

So, in your specific case, setting it to `localDateTime` should fix it:

```xml
<h:outputText value="#{transaction.date}">
    <f:convertDateTime type="localDateTime" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
</h:outputText>
```

---

In case it is output-only and you happen to use the utility library [OmniFaces](https://omnifaces.org) of version 3.6 or newer, then you can also use the [`#{of:formatDate()}`](https://omnifaces.org/docs/vdldoc/4.0/of/formatDate.fn.html) function instead. It is [capable](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/c0bb7e5fb23367d3616074ff4ebdc562e3c24749/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/util/Utils.java#L928) of automatically detecting the date type and it currently supports all known instances of `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar` and `java.time.Temporal`.

```xml
#{of:formatDate(transaction.date, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')}
```